# WordPress HTTPS - '... better to use HTTP for installation ...'

Tags: redirect, https, http

I've made a few test installation of WordPress, including Multi-Site, using `https://www.` - and haven't encountered any specific problems or issues.

I aim to make `https://www.` the default, site-wide. So, SiteUrl, Homepage, and Domain will all be: `https://www.`.

According to WordPress: HTTPS for WordPress - https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/#implementing-https-for-wordpress:

> Normally install WordPress (HTTP URL or HTTPS both will work, better
>   to use HTTP for installation)

**Question #1:**

Given that WordPress' instruction is to install using HTTP, and then update SitURL and others to HTTPS, why would installing using HTTP be *better* than HTTPS?

**Question #2: Installing using HTTPS and SEO**

Many people suggest using *.htaccess* to forward all HTTP requests to HTTPS. And, the same recommend *.htaccess 301 permanent redirect* for the benefit of SEO. Could installing WordPress using HTTPS have any negative repercussion from a SEO perspective?

Of course, using HTTPS to install WordPress is not the same as using .htaccess to redirect and force `https://www.` - but I expect both of these approaches to be equally valid from a SEO & Search Indexing perspective.

**Question #3: SSL / HTTPS Plugin**

If my aim is to have the whole website HTTPS, including front & back end, then should I *simply* install using HTTPS?

Given this, seems an over-kill to use any Plugins. I appreciate the flexibility such Plugins provide, but - I want the whole site to be `https://www.` and installing HTTPS seems the most *proper* way.

Comment: "better to use HTTP for installation" - I can't think of a good reason for that, except one fewer moving parts to go wrong in your server set-up, or perhaps the installation process pulls in some external resource over HTTP only that'd cause warnings or fail to load if included or iframed into an HTTPS page - and since installation is a rare operation that might not be caught as easily as if it were in the admin site. But I really doubt either of those are true.

Comment: I am anticipating some issues with loading placeholder content from Theme XML files. Most iFramed content these days provide the HTTPS option too. I have read about cases where Plugins and others have HTTP declared within their URIs - and it is this last point that makes me lean towards a Plugin-based solution for delivering the website using HTTPS.

Comment: **Update:** turns out that HTTPS isn't a problem as such, but installing as HTTP then updating to HTTPS prior to activating Multisite is preferred. WPMS recommends using _Naked Domain Names_, I still want use of CNAME so will use _.htaccess_ to force _www._ and stick with `https://www.`. Importing placeholder content into WordPress from Theme XML won't be a problem for the Theme I'm using.